# Poisson bracket of the angular momentum and a scalar function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, poisson-brackets

In the context of the Hamiltonian mechanics, I am trying to demonstrate the following statement:

> For any scalar function $f$, just as the dot product $\boldsymbol{q}·\boldsymbol{p}$, the Poisson Brackets with the components of the angular momentum vanishes: $
> \left[L_{i}, f\right] = 0$

**My attempt**

For the scalar product $\boldsymbol{q}·\boldsymbol{p}$, making use of the expression of the angular momentum in terms of the Levi-Civita symbol, $L_i =\epsilon_{i r s} q_{r} p_{S}$, I can see that the statement is true:

$$
\left[L_{i}, q_{j} p_{j}\right]=\frac{\partial L_{i}}{\partial q_{k}} q_{j} \frac{\partial p_{j}}{\partial p_{k}}-\frac{\partial L_{i}}{\partial p_{k}} p_{j} \frac{\partial q_{j}}{\partial q_{k}}=q_{j} \frac{\partial L_{i}}{\partial q_{j}}-p_{j} \frac{\partial L_{i}}{\partial p_{j}}
$$

$$
=q_{j} \frac{\partial \epsilon_{i r s} q_{r} p_{s}}{\partial q_{j}}-p_{j} \frac{\partial \epsilon_{i r s} q_{r} p_{s}}{\partial p_{j}}=\epsilon_{i j s} q_{j} p_{s}-\epsilon_{i r s} q_{r} p_{s} = 0
$$

However, I cannot find a way to prove this for the case of a general scalar function $f$. How could the statement be reasoned?

Comment: It appears in one of my class exercises. Indeed, the statement is supposed to be correct, although I also find the part corresponding to the scalar function a bit strange

Comment: I have seen for instance that this statement is used to argue that, in the case of a particle of magnetic moment $\boldsymbol{\mu} \equiv \gamma \boldsymbol{L}$ in a magnetic field $\boldsymbol{B}$, the Poisson Bracket $\left[\boldsymbol{L}, \frac{p^{2}}{2 m}\right]$ is zero.

Comment: It is the square of the linear momentum, $p^2=\boldsymbol{p}·\boldsymbol{p}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128139/discussion-between-invenietis-and-kam-kah-sen).

Comment: as it stands the statement is false. the function $f$ must be a scalar function constructed out of $p$, $q$ **only**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of Hamiltonian mechanics, Poisson-commuting with $L_i$ is the *definition* of being a scalar function.

In general, a tensor $T$ of rank $2j$ is by definition a function that satisfies
$$
\{L^i,T^a\}=t^i{}^a{}_b T^b
$$
where $t^i$ are the matrices that generate $SO(3)$ in the $2j+1$ dimensional representation. A scalar is $j=0$ so the one-dimensional representation, whose generators vanish, $t^i=0$. So a scalar Poisson-commutes with $L_i$, by very definition of being a scalar.

If you don't like this, you will need to come up with an alternative definition of being a scalar. If you try, you'll convince yourself that all attempts lead to the condition $\{L_i,T\}=0$ one way or another, so there is no good alternative definition, really. The underlying reason is that, scalar means invariant under rotations, and $L_i$ are precisely the generators of rotations, implemented via $\{L_i,\cdot\}$, so being a scalar is quite literally being annihilated by this operator.

Comment: So, for every non-vectorial function (say the square of the linear momentum, $p^2$, or a combination with the $q$ coordinate such as $q^3p^5$), we can assure that it will automatically Poisson-Commute with the components of the angular momentum, $L_i$?

Comment: @Invenietis I don't know what "non-vectorial function" means, and I'm sure that if you try to come up with a precise definition, you'll be able to convince yourself that there is no good definition other than "a function that Poisson-commutes with $L$". Can I invite you to try to find a precise definition of "non-vectorial function"?

Comment: (But anyway, more to your question: any function of $q_i,p_i$ that depends on these variables *only* through the combinations $\sum_i q_i^2, \sum_i p_i^2,\sum_i q_ip_i$, will Poisson-commute with $L$. Any (analytic) function that depends on $q_i,p_i$ in a way that does *not* involve these combinations only, will *not* Poisson-commute.)

Comment: If $a\neq 0$ is a constant vector, $f(x,p) = a \cdot p$ is a scalar but it is not invariant under rotations...I understand that you are considerinf  functions of $x$ and $p$ only, but in the original question this constraint is not assumed. I think that the original question is ambiguous. Your correct answer is the previous comment actually.

Comment: (Adding the absolute value of the cross product of the considered vectors to the permitted possibilities.)

Comment: @ValterMoretti Your $f$ is neither invariant under rotations nor does it commute with $L_i$, does it? I believe $\{\vec L,\vec a\cdot\vec p\}=\vec a\times\vec p\neq0$, or did I mess up the calculation?

Comment: Yes, but it is a *scalar* function.

Comment: @ValterMoretti It is... not. A scalar does not mean "a number". The first component of $p_i$ is also "a number", yet it is clearly not a scalar. "Scalar" means "transforms under the trivial representation of whatever group is relevant to the problem at hand". Here "scalar" means scalar under O(3). Your function is not a scalar under O(3).

Comment: yes, if interpreting in that way the term "scalar", the answer is almost a tautology.

Comment: In the case of $f(x,p) = a \cdot p$ or equivalent 'scalar' functions, I think it is also important to say that these will be invariant under the rotation group if you actually consider $a$ as a vector, which would automatically imply that it transforms under $O(3)$, thus making this function invariant under rotations. The only thing is that in this case, the generator of rotations in $a$ would not be generated by the components of $L$.